# Как напечатать символы U+2610 и U+2612 в консоли Windows с помощью Java?

Tags: java, windows, консоль, unicode

Что делаю:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char i = 0x25A0;
        System.out.println(i);
        i = 0x2612;
        System.out.println(i);
        i = 0x2610;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Что получаю в IDE:

[image: Результат в IDE]

Что получаю в консоли:

[image: Результат в консоли]

Кодировка IDE UTF-8, Windows10, локаль русская, шрифты побовал Consolas и Lucida Console - всегда в IDE все ок, а в консоли нет. Кодировка 65001 для консоли не помогла. Думаю, проблема в кодировке.
Как добиться правильного отображения символов?

Comment: к сожалею в консоли Windows некоторые символы из юникода не отображаются корректно и переключение страницы не поможет. в некоторых случаях помогает обращение к WinApi напрямую, но у меня не получилось с вашим набором символов.

Comment: Появилась идея, что дело в отсутствии этих символов в шрифтах Consolas и Lucida Console.

Comment: а что вы хотите получить? зачем вы хотите напечатать эти символы в консоли?

Comment: Написал консольный морской бой. Эти символы отлично смотрелись в консоли IDE и позволяли сделать полноценное понятное поле.

Comment: значит настало время сделать GUI :)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman или переходить на линукс, ага)

Comment: [DejaVU Sans Mono](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/) шрифт  в консоли `cmd` способен изобразить ети симболи `■☒☐`, [доступный для загрузки](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans-mono).